# How to import AuthContext created in App.js in other components

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-context

I am following the procedures mentioned in React navigation Docs for implementing Authentication using Expo secure Store. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

I tried to minimise their code snippet as short as possible if this is not clear please refer this [snippet](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Getting%20started%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fauth-flow.js)

```
//some imports

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

function SplashScreen() {
    //some jsx
}

function HomeScreen() {
  const { signOut } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
  //somejsx
  );
}

function SignInScreen() {

  const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
return (//somejsx);

}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App({ navigation }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    (prevState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            userToken: action.token,
            isLoading: false,
          };
        case 'SIGN_IN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: false,
            userToken: action.token,
          };
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: true,
            userToken: null,
          };
      }
    },
    {
      isLoading: true,
      isSignout: false,
      userToken: null,
    }
  );

  

  const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn:  () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' }),
      signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' }),
      signUp:  () =>  dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy' });
    }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          {state.isLoading ? (

            <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
          ) : state.userToken == null ? (

            <Stack.Screen
              name="SignIn"
              component={SignInScreen}
            />
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**Now Coming to my Issue**, In the given snippet they used the Authcontext they created in the login and register screens directly

```
const { signOut } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
```

But in my use case scenario i have to use the signOut function outside the App component, in my signOut screen.

When i tried to use the AuthContext in a separate file, react native is throwing up an error "can't find variable AuthContext". I encoded My App component with the  and also provided the value with correct syntax.

I am not sure if i have to import the AuthContext in the login and register components.

**Any help would be highly appreciated, Thanks in Advance.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the compenent where you need to use the context, like this as example

```
<AuthenticationProvider>
    <TheComponent/>
</AuthenticationProvider>
```

You can first create a component called Provider

```
   

 const Providers: FC = (props) => (
    <AuthenticationProvider>
        {props.children}
    </AuthenticationProvider>
    );
    
    export default Providers;
```

and then pass your component as children

Comment: Hi Andrainiony, I  did not get what you are saying completly. If you don't mind, Would you Please provide some guidance for this particular useCase?    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In App.js:

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
```

In SignInScreen.js:

```
import { AuthContext } from 'App.js'
```